# c code file read error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a work about reading a image in directory. 
In my code fd.name is okay.
But Mat image0 = imread(fd.name) is NULL data.
So, image0 is NULL
What's the problem?

```
struct _finddata_t fd;
intptr_t handle;
if ((handle = _findfirst(path.c_str(), &fd)) == -1L)
    cout << "No file in directory!" << endl;
do
{

    Mat image0 = imread(fd.name);
    if (!image0.data)
        continue;
    Mat image;
    cvtColor(image0, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    const int width = image.cols;
    const int height = image.rows;


    vector<feature_P> vec;

    SIFT(image, vec);


    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec.at(i).x > 4 && vec.at(i).x < height - 4 && vec.at(i).y > 4 && vec.at(i).y < width - 4)
        {
            int result = LBP(image, vec.at(i).x, vec.at(i).y);
            int fake = rand() % 250 + 100;
            fprintf(fp, "+1 1:%d\n-1 1:%d\n", result, fake);
        }
    }
    cout << fd.name << endl;
} while (_findnext(handle, &fd) == 0);
_findclose(handle);
```

Comment: That's C++, not C.

Comment: _"fd.name is okay"_ are you sure? print out the name and be sure that is a valid path to an image

Comment: Hi, in the current state your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: What does the documentation for `imread` say about when it returns NULL? I'd suspect that it does so when either the filename is invalid or the file format isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `fd.name` is only file name and relative to `path`, `imread` can't "guess" the folder path you gave to `_findfirst`

You should try to open `path + "\\" + fd.name` (assuming `path` not already end with a backslash...)

For example:

```
std::string fullFileName = path + "\\" + fd.name;
Mat image0 = imread(fullFileName.c_str());
```

BTW: the proper way to check if failed to read image is:

```
if(image.empty())
```

Comment: It dosen't wrok...so sad

Comment: string path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train\\*.jpg"; this is my path code

Comment: @차진혁 So, you should try to open `std::string("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train\\") +  fd.name` not just `fd.name`.